# C# text box when clicked displays drop down with previous values entered

Tags: c#

Using visual studio and added a text box for searching and it is automatically adding a drop down displaying previous entered text double spaced.  How to get rid of it?  I’ve tried everything but the correct fix. Code was added in Site.Master Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/" title="Home">Live</a>

                <!-- Search Text Box -->
                <div style="margin-right: 0px; padding-right:0px; float:left;">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="ignore-css" ID="txtSearchBox" placeholder="Search" style="margin-top: 15px; background-color: #fff; margin-right: 0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 22px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <!-- Search Button -->
                <div style="margin-left: 0px; padding-left:0px; float:left;">
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnSearch" ImageUrl="~/images/searchIcon.png" CssClass="btnSearch" OnClick="imgSearchButton_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right dropdown-ql">
              <button class="dropbtn-ql">Quick Links & LCOM</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content-ql" id="ddlQuickLinks" runat="server"></div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off autocomplete by adding `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check this -> [HTML  autocomplete Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)
Html input autocomplete attribute. Just set off in order to get rid of this.